# Stop Strut2 from automatically converting non-ascii characters to unicode value

Tags: jsp, encoding, struts2

Suppose `name` contains non-ascii characters, when I use `<s:property value="name" />`, Struts automatically converts those characters to things like `&#20165;`.

This is completely unnecessary as I declares

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>`
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and

```
struts.i18n.encoding=UTF-8
```

It makes the html source completely unreadable on client side while increasing the size of the page tremendously.

I know `<s:property value="name" escapeHtml="false" />` could solve my problem. But that's not the point. This option is intended to be used when I don't want escapeHtml at all. What I want is escape Html properly while leaving UTF-8 characters alone! I guess setting a property somewhere should solve the problem, but where? I searched for quite a long time and can't find a solution.

Comment: First meta tage is no longer work in struts2 and what you have done seems ok

Comment: @umesh Thank you. But what do you mean by 'seems ok'?

Comment: I mean as per your post everything seems fine to me. i saw similar issue with Chinese character display.here is a ling for the similar post may be it can help you a bit http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-chinese-localization-issue/

Comment: I could be wrong but this seems to be container issue. In Tomcat you should add a line for encoding in server.xml. Don't know about other containers but shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Comment: @umesh the post you referred me to output things like `&#20165;` for `<s:property />` tag generated results while it output UTF-8 characters for `<s:text />` tag generated results (even though `.properties` files are always converted by `native2ascii` to unicode points, the output generated by `s:text` is processed back to UTF-8 chars)

Comment: @doctrey This seems to be a `<s:property />` specific issue. Anyway, I am using Tomcat6, can you elaborate on how to do that? I tried a few after searching on Google and am not sure what specific method you are referring to.

Comment: Not sure what the comment about meta tags and Struts2 means. Meta tags are interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Something that might interest the OP, in that this seems to be mostly a development issue is if you inspect the page with firebug it provides exactly the kind of view the OP is looking for.  That is encoded unicode characters are shown as characters while html encoded entities are shown still encoded. Then you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thank you @Quaternion. Your suggestion on FireBug is very helpful. But I still hope there's a solution for this tedious thing. And Steven did just that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something specific to the `<s:property/>` tag. You can use `<c:out/>` instead, which will escape XML characters without altering the Unicode characters. Try this:

```
<c:out value="${action.name}"/>
```

This is the JSTL equivalent of `<s:property value="name"/>`.

Comment: The s:property tag uses the escape methods of org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils which for some reason always encode the non ascii unicode characters. I tested all kinds of things and nothing in struts2 seems to be able to do this directly, so score one for the jstl.

Comment: Thanks for the additional sleuthing, Quaternion!

Comment: @Quaternion, I read the Struts2 source code and noticed about the `StringEscapeUtils` as well. I almost believed that this could not possibly be solved. I know about jstl, how stupid I was not to come up with such a solution.

Comment: @Steven, you gave a great solution. This work around doe have a downside, but much better than not having it!

Comment: What down side did you encounter?

Comment: @Steven Thank you so much for your question. Originally, I thought this wouldn't work correctly inside `<s:iterator>`. But to my astonishment, it worked!

Comment: @Steven Now I have a new question. Why do we need `<s:property>` then?

Comment: You don't really. Also, you can use <c:forEach> instead of <s:iterator>.